# Size of list in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

According to this: 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_collections_c.html

An item in a list can be max 64k.

Also it states that you can have 64k items in a list.

1. Does that mean that I can have (1024 * 64 = 65536) items of 64k in a list, map or set?
2. Or does it mean that I can have (65536/size of internal reference type to each item) items of 64k in a list, map or set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means you'll have max 65536 items in a collection. And each item in your collection won't be greater than 65536.